# How to emulate this augmented reality 3D banner text mock-up in perspective with Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-photoshop, mockup

[image]

This is from Zach Liebermann's Weird Type app screenshots on the iPhone. I want to create a mockup screenshot of an AR app that has this mechanism, on Photoshop and then import it to XD.

If I were to make a twirly banner from a primitive object, I, unfortunately, don't have much experience with 3D.

I tried using the `Free Transform` tool such as warping and distorting. I've tried using the `Vanishing Point filter` and it somewhat worked but the results were not similar enough.

Can someone point out how I can emulate this manually (with 2D tools) on Photoshop?

Comment: The background of the image on the left is almost colorless and is placed in perspective while it is colored and flat in the other image. The background also lacks the lights and shadows that in the image on the right create the effect of depth

Comment: The clou of the phone app is the ability to track the movement of the phone and change the view plausibly as the phone moves. As static images the effect is poor. without color and shading. But Photoshop 2020 should have custom warp with freely selectable warp grid dimensions, not only 3x3 as earlier. With it you should get the same as with Illustrator's Envelope Distortion > Make with mesh. Editing is very difficult and most complex swirls are impossible without splitting the text into parts. 3D software makes everything more easily, but it isn't what's asked.

Comment: How about Puppet Warp?

Comment: @LeoNas Making twisted or waving text ribbons with continuous surface tangents needs a genius to place and move the nodes of Puppet warp.

Comment: I make some works for AR and I use Blender3d. The Puppet Warp try was just an idea, but I know it is a big challenge.